# Calling method from another class that's an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am calling a method from another class. The method contains an integer array. I am trying to stay away from inputting the index manually.

I am trying to search for numbers within a range.

example:
ArrayList: {1,5}, {5,10}, {10,15}

Input: enter 3

Process: search for number within range

output: 1,5

The driver class is storing the objects from the main class called Numbers into ArrayList. The main class have an accessor call getNumbers. getNumbers contains an integer array with 2 elements. The driver is calling getNumbers to validate the entry that users input.

The code below works but I'm told it's consider bad coding to code entering the indexes. I want to know how to output the array from getNumber method without knowing the array length of getNumber?

example of what I have:

```
for(int i = 0; i < example.size(); i++) 
         //number is the integer that is inputted.
         if(example.get(i).getNumbers()[1] > number &&
         example.get(i).getNumbers()[0] <= numbers)
            System.out.println(example.get(i));
```

Should I add another for loop?

example of what I am thinking of:

```
for(int i = 0; i < example.size(); i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < example.get(i).getNumbers.length; j++){
         if(example.get(i).getNumbers()[j] > number &&
         example.get(i).getNumbers()[j] <= numbers)
            System.out.println(example.get(i));
  }
}
```

Edit: Changed how I worded some things and fixed the code of what I think I should do.

Comment: Format your code correctly by indenting - the way you're presenting it now is also an example of bad coding.

Comment: Your question is also badly structured, consider editing.  Include important classes that you use like what class is your `example`, and what is `ListArray`?

Comment: I edited the way I worded things. Hope it makes more sense now. If not please point it out and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: @Touchpad You can look at the code below, you need to modify the Numbers class as below to hold two elements

Answer (score 1):

> The code below works but I'm told it's consider bad coding to code
>   entering the indexes. I want to know how to output the array from
>   getNumber method without knowing the array length of getNumber ?

If you don't want to do the validations with array `indexes` for your first element and second element in the array, then you can solve the problem by modifying your `Numbers` `class` as shown below:

(1) Define two `int` variable members (currently you have only one)

(2) Add a method `isInLimits(int input)` to validate the range

(3) Override `toString`() which can be used to print the object as String

**Numbers class (modified):**

```
public static class Numbers {

        private int firstElement;
        private int secondElement;

        public int getFirstElement() {
            return firstElement;
        }
        public void setFirstElement(int firstElement) {
            this.firstElement = firstElement;
        }
        public int getSecondElement() {
            return secondElement;
        }
        public void setSecondElement(int secondElement) {
            this.secondElement = secondElement;
        }

        //checks the input is in the range of this object elements
        public boolean isInLimits(int input) {
            if(input >= firstElement && input < secondElement) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{"+firstElement+","+secondElement+"}";
        }
    }
```

**Usage of Numbers Class:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      int userInput = 10; //get it from user 

      List<Numbers> example = new ArrayList<>();
      //Add Numbers objects to example list

       for(int i=0;i< example.size();i++) {
            Number numberTemp = example.get(i);
            //call Numbers object's isInLimits
            if(numberTemp.isInLimits(userInput)) {
                System.out.println(numberTemp);
            }
        }
    }
```